# Is there a risk of losing data with Azure Resource Mover and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to move the Azure SQL Server resource of my company to a new region (from West-Europe to France-Central) with the Azure Resource Mover. I am wondering if the process can result in any data loss. In particular, during the data copy process, if data that is saved while copying the database will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft’s [Azure Resource Mover documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/), there’s a page with details [About the move process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/about-move-process#move-impact). According to the *Move Impact* section:

> No data loss expected, but some downtime to move resources.

This is reiterated in the [Move Azure SQL Database resources to another region tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-sql#move-databases), under *Move Databases*, which is obviously specific to Azure SQL Database resources:

> Some downtime occurs for SQL databases during the commit process. Committed databases and elastic pools are now in a *Delete source pending* state. After the commit, update database-related settings, including firewall rules, policies, and alerts, on the target database.

Given that, you should be safe—but *only* because you won’t be able to save *any* data during the move process.

Obviously, that may effectively result in data loss for your application if it doesn’t have any fault tolerance built in (such as a retry for saving data)—or, at least, a warning for customers that the application is temporarily unavailable before they commit to any write operations. Thus, the practical impact is really dependent on how your application is designed.